# Groovy issue when checking maps in each closure

Tags: groovy, hashmap, closures, each

I have a utility method that needs to check if a `Map<String,Integer>` contains entries (keys) whose values are *all* zero (0):

```
def mapIsAllZeros(Map<String,Integer> toCheck) {
    println toCheck
    toCheck.each {
        if(it.value != 0) {
            return false
        } else {
            println "Value is : " + it.value
        }
    }

    println "Returning true..."
    true
}
```

Hence:

```
Map<String,Integer> m1 = new HashMap<String,Integer>()
m1.put("fizz", 0)
m1.put("buzz", 0)

Map<String,Integer> m2 = new HashMap<String,Integer>()
m2.put("fizz", 0)
m2.put("buzz", 1)

boolean m1Check = mapIsAllZeros(m1) // TRUE
boolean m2Check = mapIsAllZeros(m2) // FALSE
```

However when I run this method passing it `m2` I get:

```
[fizz:0, buzz:1]
Value is : 0
Value is : 0
Returning true...
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`each` can not return.  use `find` instead.  also this can be done in one line: `[fizz:0, buzz:1].every{!it.value}`

```
def mapIsAllZeros(Map<String,Integer> toCheck) {
    return toCheck.values().every{it==0}
}
assert !mapIsAllZeros([fizz: 0, buzz: 1])
assert !mapIsAllZeros([fizz: 1, buzz: 1])
assert mapIsAllZeros([fizz: 0, buzz: 0])
assert !mapIsAllZeros([fizz: null, buzz: null])
```

**Edit: thanks to @dmahapatro: as the methods's name suggest a proper check against zero, let's not work with groovy-truth, so `null`:s wont result into something misleading**

Comment: Thanks @cfrick (+1) - can you provide a complete code example? I'm having a tough time seeing the forest through the trees here... thanks again!

Comment: Oops, didn't see that you already answered this. I'd actually forgotten about `every`. Nice solution.

Comment: @Steinar the more the merrier ;)

Comment: I suppose this `assert !mapIsAllZeros([fizz: null, buzz: null])` will fail. :) Same is applicable with my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the return statement returns from the `each` closure, not from the `mapIsAllZeros` method. I.e. the closure returns false and then `each` continues the iteration.

So you should use something other than `each`. For instance, using `find`:

```
boolean mapIsAllZeros(Map<String, Integer> toCheck) {
    !(toCheck.find { it.value != 0 })
}
```

Another alternative is to use a for loop:

```
boolean mapIsAllZeros(Map<String, Integer> toCheck) {
    for (entry in toCheck.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.value != 0) 
           return false
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with returning from `each` closure was already clarified well, nevertheless You can also use the following piece of code (method name borrowed from @Steinar)

```
boolean mapIsAllZeros(Map<String, Integer> toCheck) {
   !toCheck.values().contains(0)
}
```

Simple and uses API that is well known.

Answer (score 1):

A solution comparing unique values:

```
def mapIsAllZeros(map) {
  map*.value.unique() == [0]
}

assert !mapIsAllZeros([fizz: 0, buzz: 1])
assert !mapIsAllZeros([fizz: 1, buzz: 1])
assert mapIsAllZeros([fizz: 0, buzz: 0])
```

Because there are not enough answers here.